# Display subchildren by signed user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am new in firebase and I need help with display subchildren of firebase which contain the same userID as signed user

[image: here is my database]
 [here is users and edu1 full show of user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCPBR.png)
I need display just subchildren of signed user

and here is my code
 private FirebaseAuth fAuth;

```
private DatabaseReference fNotesDatabase;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_education);
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child("education");


    fNotesDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String values = datas.getKey();
                arraylist.add(values);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Education.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, arraylist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the exact data that you want to display in your ListView?

Comment: So in case of `Y5o...`, you want to ListView that will contain a single record of type String named `edu1`?

Comment: I want display just subchildren which cantain same user ID as is current 
logged in user

Comment: Yes Alex i want just single record or when there will more subchildren than 1 so all where is this same user ID

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the content of `Y5o...` on both places, `Notes` and `Users`.

Comment: check update there is image

Comment: I see that there is another pushed object within it. I think you should reconsider your database schema, so it can be queried according to the id of the user you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userId = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
    fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child("education");


    fNotesDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String values = datas.getKey();

               db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(values).orderByKey().equalTo(userId);
               db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
                   @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   //get data
             }

                    @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
             });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here you add reference to `education` then retrieve the direct children under `education` then using `orderByKey()` you can check if there is a key equal to the current logged in user and retrieve the data.

Comment: Hello its not work its dont display anythink in your code is db as querry or how you it define ?

Comment: when i define db as DatabaseReference i get error that "Incompatible types Required: DtabaseReference Found:Query "

Comment: Yes use Query instead

Comment: still not working because it not display any item in listview

Comment: In the second onDataChange you should add items to listview

Comment: yes i did it i add there this all " String values = datas.getKey();
                                arraylist.add(values);
                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Education.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, arraylist);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);" is it right ?

Comment: U need to retrieve the values that are inside the userid in the second ondatachange

Comment: i did it as i said in upper coment there is part of code which i added there

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and see if it is working with you :

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 // get the current user-id to read data easly
String  currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()             
   .getReference().child("notes").child("education");
 // get data to them
userRef.child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(
            new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
         for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String values = datas.getKey();
            arraylist.add(values);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Education.this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, 
             arraylist);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a data structure like `/Education/Notes/$uid`. So to just read the notes of the currently signed in user, do:

```
fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child("education");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

fNotesDatabase.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work Frank because he has `edu1` or `edu2` Between the `education` node and the `userid`

Comment: Oh darn, I missed that. That indeed requires an inverse index.